# When to use Category rather than Object?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, types, dataset

I have a CSV dataset with 40 features that I am handling with Pandas. 7 features are continuous (`int32`) and the rest of them are categorical.

My question is :

Should I use the `dtype('category')` of Pandas for the categorical features, or can I let the default `dtype('object')`?

Comment: No reason not to use a category here. Will also save a lot of space/memory if the strings are very long (you can check with `info()` or `memory_usage()` btw. Also 't' in dtype is not capitalized.

Answer (score 27):

Use a category when there is lots of repetition that you expect to exploit.

For example, suppose I want the aggregate size per exchange for a large table of trades. Using the default `object` is totally reasonable:

```
In [6]: %timeit trades.groupby('exch')['size'].sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 ms per loop
```

But since the list of possible exchanges is pretty small, and because there is lots of repetition, I could make this faster by using a `category`:

```
In [7]: trades['exch'] = trades['exch'].astype('category')

In [8]: %timeit trades.groupby('exch')['size'].sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 702 µs per loop
```

---

Note that categories are really a form of *dynamic enumeration*. They are most useful if the range of possible values is fixed and finite.

Comment: Thanks for your answers !

So Categorical type is better for memory optimization.

Comment: The other reason to use Categoricals, is that they *can* provide (as its not the default), an *ordering* to your categories. E.g. maybe ['small','medium','large']. Then you can sort by this! See the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#sorting-and-order)

Answer (score 24):

The Pandas documentation has a [concise section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) on when to use the `categorical`data type:

> The categorical data type is useful in the following cases:
>
> - A string variable consisting of only a few different values.
>     Converting such a string variable to a categorical variable will save
>     some memory, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#categorical-memory).
> - The lexical order of a variable is not the same
>     as the logical order (“one”, “two”, “three”). By converting to a
>     categorical and specifying an order on the categories, sorting and
>     min/max will use the logical order instead of the lexical order, see
>     [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#categorical-sort).
> - As a signal to other Python libraries that this column should be
>     treated as a categorical variable (e.g. to use suitable statistical
>     methods or plot types).

Comment: What is the difference between object and categorical?
Which is equivalent to R "factors"?

Comment: Pandas' categorical is equivalent to R's factors. Object is the default generic data reference for anything not otherwise identified (actully a numpy object array). Strings default to being labelled as object type because strings are so flexibly open, but you can explicitly change the column type to a [Pandas stringDtype column](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-data-types).